# how to check method invocation in python plugin of sonarqube

Tags: python, sonarqube

I want to develop customed python plugin and create my own python checker. In sonarqube java plugin, I can use 'MethodInvocationTree ' to get and check arguments in method invocation. But how can I do the same thing in pythong plugin?

Comment: If you want to check command line arguments check for `argparse` and if you want to check the arguments passed to functions check for `*args` and `**kwargs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: SonarPython does not have a custom rules API (except using XPath expressions). To extend it, you will have to fork the [sonar-python](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python) repository, which is not recommended. It will require a lot of effort to merge each release coming from the original repository. It is preferable to describe your rule ideas on [sonarqube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) or create a github pull request on [sonar-python](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python).

Unlike SonarJava, SonarPython does not have a strongly typed AST (abstract syntax tree), you have to subscribe and visit a tree of AstNode.

To visualize how AST nodes are structured, you should use "PythonToolkit" (open sonar-python/sslr-python-toolkit/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/toolkit/PythonToolkit.java and execute "main")
Then write in the source code panel the bellow example and press the "Parse source code" button:

```
print("a")
o.foo()
```

By exploring the tree, you will see that there's no "MethodInvocation".
But you can subscribe to PythonGrammar.TRAILER, then check that:

```
trailerNode.getFirstChild().is(PythonPunctuator.LPARENTHESIS)
```

Comment: That python toolkit is very useful, I can see AST very clearly. I have used PythonGrammar.TRAILER to find out PythonPunctuator.LPARENTHESIS then get method invocation info include method name and arguments.